# Endless animation?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to make DoubleAnimation continue forever (no loop, just continue without stop)?

Comment: @Dinah, sure. Because I don't have answers. As you can see in this very question, the most of "answerers" don't even understand the question. It seems today's SO is all about point begging.

Comment: @user: If most the answerers don't understand the question then you should edit the question to make it more clear what you're asking.

Comment: @rossisdead, if you don't understand it - read carefully, ask for explanation or just don't answer. Easy. But the most of people here don't even read tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is technically impossible to continue the animation forever (Double has a certain maximum value), the closest you could get is animate to Double.MaxValue in the according amount of time you should be able to calculate.

However, we may be able to give you a better solution if you tell us what exactly you need this animation for.

Comment: But, what duration is necessary in this case? Calculated speed will be too slow. I just need to restart animation on the certain condition programmatically, because "To" value is too complex and can change in runtime.

Comment: Duration = Change in Value / Speed, as always. What do you mean with "Calculated speed will be too slow"? Why can the "To" value change? Sorry, but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Sure. In this case, Speed = double.MaxValue / .... what value? It won't work properly. Just try it.

Comment: Ah I see the problem is that the duration would exceed the MaxValue of TimeSpan right? In this case, just go after TimeSpan.MaxValue - 29,247 years should be sufficient for most applications.

Comment: It's too perverted :) I tried animating the property manually, works much better. BTW, it's possible to use Duration.Forever, and animation accepts this value. But it just doesn't do anything then.

Answer (score 4):

Animations and StoryBoards in WPF have a RepeatBehavior property that you can set to "Forever". This will tell your animation to repeat forever until you tell it to stop.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.repeatbehavior.aspx

Comment: Didn't the questioner say he didn't want to use loops?

Answer (score 1):

Without a loop implies you have new frames to display in the animation. So this question is equivalent to "can I produce a movie than runs forever?" Unless you can automatically generate some animation content (which computationally is perfectly feasible) - the answer is "no".

However, for examples of "endless" animations, look at any of the many flash pages online. For example;

http://flintparticles.org/blog/examples